# How can I figure out how much money a political lobbying group has given to my congressman?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance, lobbying, reference-request

I have seen some messages lately from my district representative that are essentially talking points of a political lobbying group. I would like to find out if and how much money he has received from this lobbying group.

Where can I find a reliable resource that shows all donations to a politician?

- Resources provided must include donations from pro-Israel lobbying groups (Thanks DM for informing me that AIPAC does not directly provide $$)

Comment: I removed the exact lobbying group from the question because, as you said yourself, you are looking for a general answer, not one specific to that one group.

Comment: @Philipp The problem with the edit is that I am primarily concerned with AIPAC in my question, an answer that did not include AIPAC would not sufficiently answer my question.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, " AIPAC is not a political action committee, and does not directly donate to campaign contributions."  If you want contributions by their individual members, that's going to be trickier.

Comment: @DM Thanks, I did not realize that.  I will have to amend the question to pro-Israel Lobbying Groups

Comment: Good answers below; a good general site for such information is  https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 17):

If you looking in the USA, the source of data would ultimately come from legally required campaign finance and financial disclosures filed with the FEC (Federal Elections Commission).

[FEC: Campaign Finance Data](https://www.fec.gov/data/)

[FEC: Campaign Finance Disclosure Search](https://www.fec.gov/finance/disclosure/disclosure_data_search.shtml)

However, things get murkier with assorted PACS, "dark money" and third party "independent" expenditures.

One particular group that tries to consolidate that information and give a more complete picture is the Center for Responsive Politics, a non-partisan group dedicated to a more transparent process.  They not only have good resources regarding how everything works, but they do data consolidation and analysis that you can sort and customize in a number of different ways (what industries contributed most heavily, what percentage of donations fell into particular donation size tiers, etc).

[OpenSecrets.org](http://www.opensecrets.org)

Comment: Ah Citizens United - "Money is our voice! We must be heard!" "Okay fine, who are you talking to and what are you saying?" "None of your business, stop violating my rights as a corporation!"

Answer (score 9):

PoloHoleSet's answer covers the federal level.  Below that, individual states usually have their own organizations for tracking this data and making it available.  They will often track this kind of data for publicly elected officials at the state level and below, such as counties and cities.

An example is the [Washington State Public Disclosure Commission](https://www.pdc.wa.gov/).

You'll have to search for your own state's equivalent organization.

Comment: Good catch.  I was thinking strictly Congress when I answered.